# Leave as default type on generic type parameter

Tags: typescript

I am trying to bypass some optional generic type parameter and leave it as a default that has been defined.

This is an example script:

```js
interface Foo<T, T1 = string, T2 = boolean> {
    ID: T
    Name: T1
    IsActive: T2
}
```

There is 3 type parameters are following:

- `T` -- it's required
- `T1` -- optional, default is `string`
- `T2` -- optional, default is `boolean`

I want to create `data` with specification below:

- `T` -- `number`
- `T1` -- <DEFAULT which is `string`>
- `T2` -- `number`

```js
const data:Foo<number, ..., number> = {
    ID: 1,
    Name: "apache", // the name type should be a string
    IsActive: 1,
}
```

Comment: There is currently no such syntax (see [ms/TS#26242](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242) for the relevant feature request).  You could possibly fake something up like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/w868Vm) shows, but it really depends on your use cases.  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: yes, but it's not really what i am looking for because in my case i am using a module that i cannot modified the origin generic implementation (Foo); anyway thank you for the answer that super-clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no such syntax to "skip" a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type argument, either for the purposes of using a [default](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) or for having the compiler infer the type argument.  There is a longstanding open feature request for this at [microsoft/TypeScript#26242](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242); if that is ever implemented, then maybe you'll be able to write `Foo<number, , number>` or `Foo<number, *, number>`, or `Foo<number, infer, number>` or something.

Until then, you'll just have to write the type in yourself as `Foo<number, string, number>`, or work around it somehow.

---

One possible workaround, if the purpose of "skipping" is to get the default, is to make a custom type to mean "skip" and rewrite your type to recognize that.  For example:

```
interface $ { ___SIGIL___: true; } // $ means "skip"
type Default<T, U> = [T] extends [$] ? U : T;
```

And now instead of `type F<T = X, U = Y, V = Z>` you'd write `type MyF<T = $, U = $, V = $> = F<Default<T, X>, Default<U, Y>, Default<V, Z>>`.  For your `Foo` it look s like:

```
type FooT1Default = Foo<any> extends Foo<any, infer T1, any> ? T1 : never;
// type FooT1Default = string

type FooT2Default = Foo<any> extends Foo<any, any, infer T2> ? T2 : never;
// type FooT2Default = boolan

type MyFoo<T, T1=$, T2=$> = 
  Foo<T, Default<T1, FooT1Default>, Default<T2, FooT2Default>>;
```

And we can test it:

```
type Example = MyFoo<number, $, number>
// type Example = Foo<number, string, number>

const data: MyFoo<number, $, number> = {
    ID: 1,
    Name: "apache", // okay
    IsActive: 1,
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.1.6#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt0B4AqAaZHARmQF5kBnMKUAcwJwCYzkAjTAGwjhAD5kA3gChko5AEkAIgC5CIsQDk4AWwizi80eIoBBBGGAA3NYUZCAvkKFgAngAcUGdMUkR4AVw5gWTrDxv8EAAekCAAJhRomH4gNgSgMNCERAT+-AD8yciyIBDGUADc1vaOmEyuHl4+0WnIwaERUdj+qbHxIIlQphmm2ci5+UW2DsgAsja++MmkACQMjLP85JMEFXCeYLgpTS5u6168q3sbuIwETuXHB7xFxSMAokEqdlws474g7sqs0ARz-V8flBeEIAPSg5DDFCPZ6vZbRT7fX6Uah0AiIoEgoQIdAgKjIMJwMBwWTvBGA5H-DHQJaCTQSGTIFL0pSqWQAIjgdkQAAsIOy8PTtHoDMZZMzLFYhKBILBECgZoJkAB9VUAZXEAHFxAAZVXK2TUdwQArISxQ5BrE5TACqtIA2jgALp1EIQcKRe0zF2ZG19HC3KVSoA)